# Lebesgue space - $L^p$ spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $X=\{a,b\}$,and $\mu(\{a\} )=1$, and $\mu(\{b\} )=\mu(X)=+\infty$ and $\mu(\emptyset)=0$. Is it truth that $L^\infty(\mu)$ is the dual space of $L^1(\mu)$. Whether $L^\infty(\mu)=L^1(\mu)^\ast$? If no, why?

Comment: Thank you very much, you help me a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Here we have

$$
\|f\|_{L^1} = \begin{cases}|f(a)| & \text{if } f(b) = 0\\ +\infty & \text{else}\end{cases}
$$
so that $L^1(\mu)  = \{f \in\mathcal{F}(\{a,b\},\Bbb R)  \mid f(b) = 0\}\simeq \Bbb R$ and $L^\infty(\mu) = \mathcal{F}(\{a,b\},\Bbb R)\simeq \Bbb R^2$.

In particular, $\dim L^1(\mu) = 1$ and $\dim L^\infty (\mu) = 2$ ...

Comment: Derive details from the proof of L∞(μ) of the following claim:
claim : If {E_α} is an arbitrary family of measurable sets on [0,1], then there is E⊂[0,1] such that:
 E contains almost all E_α;
 If F is measurable, than F contains almost all E_α and F⊇E almost everywhere.

Comment: It is better to ask this as a new question.